# GET Call on SAP Build Process Automation

Tags: build, sap-business-technology-platform

I have recently started using SAP Build Process Automation and I'm here to discuss about an issue that I'm facing and would appreciate if someone can guide me on this one.

I have created a GET action call in the action library and Published it. When I test it within the action library, it's working absolutely fine and retrieving all the details I'm asking for, using the GET Call. But, when I tried using the same GET call in the workflow automation, it's failing and not retrieving any details. The error I'm getting is "irpa_core.error.ActionRestExecutionError" and all the fields where I'm expecting data are displaying UNDEFINED as the value.

Whereas, I have a POST Call that I've created in the action library and published, which is working like a charm in the action library as well as in the automation workflow.

Can someone please tell me how to address this issue.